# Are there any models available other than VAR, VARMA for forecasting multi-variate time series data?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, predictive

I am new to time series forecasting problems. I did research on what are the different models available for forecasting multi variate time series models but ended up finding only VAR, VARMA models. I would like to know other different algorithms if there are any. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ARIMA is a great place to start. The [tutorial here](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/arima-model-time-series-forecasting-python/) is very good. It makes heavy use of the `statsmodels` package. It's not as simple to get started with as linear regression models, but based on your question I think it will be a good place for you to start.